# Python How to sort a list of list with certain conditions

Tags: list, python-2.7, sorting

I have list of list and I want to sort the list by 4 index by alphabetically but there are cases where it will be none or empty so those cases needed to be at the bottom.

For further clarfication - It should be sorted by AaBbCc then either None or empty if fine.  I just want the first items to be aplhabetically orderd case insenstive.

```
from   operator import itemgetter
list_of_list = [[0,1,2,3,'Ab'],[0,1,2,3,'bA'],[0,1,2,3,' '],[0,1,2,3,'None'], [0,1,2,3,''],[0,1,2,3,'Ca'] ]

list_of_list = sorted(list_of_list, key=itemgetter(4))

print list_of_list

Output: [[0, 1, 2, 3, ''], [0, 1, 2, 3, ' '], [0, 1, 2, 3, 'Ab'], [0, 1, 2, 3, 'Ca'], [0, 1, 2, 3, 'None'], [0, 1, 2, 3, 'bA']]
```

Should be outputed as such:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 'Ab'], [0, 1, 2, 3, 'bA'],[0, 1, 2, 3, 'Ca'], [0, 1, 2, 3, 'None'], [0, 1, 2, 3, ''], [0, 1, 2, 3, ' ']]
```

Comment: Is that 'None' meant to read None (without quotes?)

Comment: Both - meaning the same. So either its string that represents None or the actually keyword None.  THey shold go to the bottom.

Comment: you could use `(isinstance(x[4], basestring) and x[4] != "None")` to avoid the `None` string.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
>>> list_of_list = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 'Ab'],
                    [0, 1, 2, 3, 'bA'],
                    [0, 1, 2, 3, ' '],
                    [0, 1, 2, 3, None],
                    [0, 1, 2, 3, ''],
                    [0, 1, 2, 3, 'Ca']]
>>> list_of_list = sorted(list_of_list,
                          key=lambda x: x[4] if isinstance(x[4], basestring) else "",
                          reverse=True)
>>> print list_of_list
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 'bA'], [0, 1, 2, 3, 'Ca'], [0, 1, 2, 3, 'Ab'], [0, 1, 2, 3, ' '], [0, 1, 2, 3, None], [0, 1, 2, 3, '']]
```

What this does is use the fourth element as sort key if it is a string, else it will use the empty string as comparison key.

Alternately you could split your list in two lists, only sort the first one, and append the remaining elements like this:

```
list_of_list = sorted(x
                      for x in list_of_list
                      if isinstance(x[4], basestring) and len(x[4].strip())) + \
               [x
                for x in list_of_list
                if not isinstance(x[4], basestring) or not len(x[4].strip())]
print list_of_list
```

yields

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 'Ab'], [0, 1, 2, 3, 'Ca'], [0, 1, 2, 3, 'bA'], [0, 1, 2, 3, ' '], [0, 1, 2, 3, None], [0, 1, 2, 3, '']]
```

It is not entirely clear if there are other sorting criteria that you need to follow, and this solution is not totally pretty, but at least it sorts the strings in front and keeps the rest at the back.

Comment: I added more to to the criteria of sorting.  Pretty much just have letters order alphabettically first and then everything else.